# How can I programmatically add taxonomy terms to a node in hook_nodeapi()?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I am creating a module that needs to tag nodes with taxonomy terms when they are created. I have implemented hook_nodeapi() to do this, and am trying to add the term in there like so:

```
function hook_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
      $node->taxonomy = array(1 => taxonomy_get_term(1));
      node_save($node);
    break;
  }
}
```

When I call node_save(), the code just goes in to a loop, because node_save calls hook_nodeapi(). When I don't call node_save, nothing is saved. I am durned if I do, durned if I don't. Any ideas on the right way to do thi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `$op="presave"` to alter the taxonomy in the way you want and then let the taxonomy module save the terms for you. No need to use node_save afterwards. In fact node save should be avoided in nodeapi implementations for the reasons you state.

Answer (score 0):

use a `hook_form_alter()` to add it to the `$form_state`

Comment: Will this require a call to node_save() or not?